# CDT Assembly parser removes parenthesis from the code

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When I try to fetch assembly code using below CASTASMDeclaration API,

```
 org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.c.CASTASMDeclaration.getAssembly()
```

the parenthesis are removed from code.

In assembly code I have following code

```
 (uint32)sizeof(uint32))
```

Which when I try to get via getAssembly() method it removes parenthesis and gives this:

```
 uint32 sizeof uint32
```

Is there a way I get the result including parenthesis?

Comment: @howlger any hint on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no (I don't know much about CDT and C/C++). Have you debugged it to see where the parentheses are lost and where the information about the parenthesis can be found in the abstract syntax tree?